How to change this line of code? i am using php 8.2
I am getting this error when i run php 8.2 and php 8.3
Deprecated: preg_match_all(): Passing null to parameter #2 ($subject) of type string is deprecated in /home/xxx/domains/xxx.com/public_html/assets/includes/functions_one.php on line 6151
$story['mentions_users'] = [];
    $mention_regex = '/@\[([0-9]+)\]/i';
    if (preg_match_all($mention_regex, $story['postText'], $matches)) {
        foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
            $match = Wo_Secure($match);
            $match_user = Wo_UserData($match);
            $match_search = '@[' . $match . ']';
            if (isset($match_user['user_id'])) {
                $story['mentions_users'][$match_user['username']] = $match_user['name'];
            }
        }
    }

Deprecated: preg_replace_callback(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($subject) of type array|string is deprecated in /home/xxx/domains/xxxx.com/public_html/assets/includes/functions_two.php on line 7045
  $fetched_data["options"] = preg_replace_callback("/{{LANG (.*?)}}/", function($m) use ($wo) {
                return isset($wo["lang"][$m[1]]) ? $wo["lang"][$m[1]] : "";
            }, $fetched_data["options"]);
            $data[]                  = $fetched_data;
        }
    }
``

i  haven't tried much i am stuck and i am trying to figure it out why php 7.4 works without any issues

If $story['postText'] is null then it's pretty safe to assume that there will be no matches, so you can probably skip that logic entirely after checking for null.

appreciate that @David

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php check function how it work
